# How to figure out my control plane instance in EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks

From grafana dashboard, I can see that one of the 2 kubeapiservers in my EKS is having high API latency. The grafana dashboard identifies the instance using the endpoint ip.

```
root@k8scluster:~ $ kubectl describe service/kubernetes
Name:              kubernetes
Namespace:         default
Labels:            component=apiserver
                   provider=kubernetes
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          <none>
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                172.50.0.1
Port:              https  443/TCP
TargetPort:        443/TCP
Endpoints:         10.0.99.157:443,10.0.10.188:443
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Now, this endpoint (10.0.99.157) is the one which has high latency when I check from grafana. When I login to my aws console, I have access to aws ec2 instances page, but I don't have access to see the nodes in the AWS EKS page.

From EC2 console, I can figure out the 2 instances which are my running my kubeapiserver. However, I can't seem to figure out which is the one which has high latency (i.e the instance which has the endpoint ip 10.0.99.157). Is there any way I can figure out the same from ec2 console or using eks commands?

Update:

I did compare it with the IP addresses / Secondary IP addresses of both the kubeapiserver ec2 instances. But none match the endpoint ip 10.0.99.157

Comment: did you check the IP address of the EC2 instances and see if they match with `10.0.99.157` ?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu Yes I did. None of the privateip/secondary privatip match 10.0.99.157

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that the EKS K8s Control Plane is managed by AWS and therefore **outside of your management**. So, you will not be able to access the respective EC2 instances at all.

Official AWS documentation can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/clusters.html).